# Given that b is always non-zero, why `b ? --b : ++b` works, but `--b` does not?

Tags: c++, recursion

I was trying to multiply two integers using recursion, and wrote this code, accidently:

```
//the original version
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
  if ( !b )
     return 0;
  else
     return a + multiply(a, b ? --b : ++b ); //accident
}
```

I said, I wrote this accidently, because I intended to write :

`b > 0 ?  --b : ++b` instead of `b ?  --b : ++b`

I realize that  what I intended  to write [wouldn't work](http://www.ideone.com/2zAlX). But what is surprising to me is, what I did **not** intend to write [does work](http://www.ideone.com/1wf0V).

Now, I note  that `b ?--b : ++b` is basically equivalent to `--b` because `b` in else-block is guaranteed to be non-zero. So I modified the above code, replacing `b?--b:++b` with `--b`, as shown below:

```
//the modified version
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
  if ( !b )
     return 0;
  else
     return a + multiply(a, --b); //modification here
}
```

Since the original version woks, I expected the modified version to work as well. But again, to my surprise, it [doesn't work!](http://www.ideone.com/IO8K9)

- What is wrong the modified version?
- Is it not equivalent to the original version?
- Is `--b` not equivalent to `b ?--b : ++b` IF `b` is non-zero? If its equivalent, then why does the first code work but the second doesn't?

Note: here, by "work", I mean it gives the correct output. That is, it gives the *multiplication* of the integers passed to the function.

Comment: Hang on!  Can you define "work" and "doesn't work", so that we don't need to figure out what your algorithm is doing?

Comment: I don't see why the last case is a surprise, it results in a SO if b is negative to start with...

Comment: @Navaz: I see your update!  What I mean is, do we really need to consider the whole of your algorithm, or is that irrelevant?  Can you simply isolate your question to a comparison of `--b` and `b ? --b : ++b`?

Comment: @Nim: Compare both. Stackoverflow is in both cases!

Comment: @Oli: I also asked : Is `--b` not equivalent to ` b ?--b : ++b` IF `b` is non-zero?

Comment: Oveerall, I don't think this is a particularly good question.  This is trivially answerable by adding some printf statements.  (FWIW, I get a seg-fault with the first example.)

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, I don't see why you're doing `--b`/`++b` at all. There is no reason to modify the local variables. Just `b-1` and `b+1` should do the trick.

Comment: Stack overflow also. Has ideone magically DWIMified the code?

Comment: @Nawaz: No, the second case does NOT give stackoverflow, it ran out of time.  Run it on your own computer instead of wasting ideone's electricity.  It works fine.

Comment: @Ben: Well, the point is, both code is equivalent, logic-wise. If one works, I expected the second to work as well. But it doesn't.

Comment: @Nawaz: It does work.  Run it on your own system, like I already suggested.  It just takes longer, because it's being optimized differently.  If you cared about optimization and execution speed, you surely wouldn't be trusting ideone to use the right compiler flags, you'd be compiling it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR version: **The reason `b? --b: ++b` prints a result and `--b` fails with `SIGXCPU` is that ideone sets a time limit on submitted code.**  One version gets optimized better, and completes in the time allowed.  The other version gives the exact same answer, but you won't see that with ideone because it runs too slowly and gets aborted by the time limit.

---

As for why the stack overflow isn't occuring, I guess in one case the compiler must be transforming recursion into iteration (this isn't a tail call, but it is trivially transformable).

The result of the transformation would be something like http://ideone.com/AeBYI which indeed gives the correct result.  With higher optimization settings, the compiler could calculate the results at compile time and store constants in the resulting code.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Even if the SO wouldn't occur, how comes it gives correct results? It would have to iterate over almost all 32bit numbers, for each adding a 12 to the result. It doesn't seem probable to me that the end result after all overflows could be correct.

Comment: @Ben: Actually. there was a typo in my post. Please see its not that.Its rather `--b` vs. `b?--b:++b`. Both are same. But one works, other doesn't.

Comment: @Nawaz: Both work.  One just runs quicker, because the compiler precomputed the results.

Comment: @Ben: That is convincing. :-)

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work. I don't know what ideone is smoking, that code is going to overflow the stack.

**EDIT**

Tried it on gcc 4.6.0 - segfault (due to stack overflow). If however you enable `-O2` optimizations, then indeed "it works". In conclusion: it works by chance, depending on what the compiler does behind the scenes.

```
g++ -g -Wall -o f f.cpp # stack overflow
g++ -O2 -g -Wall -o f f.cpp # "works"
```

Comment: Please list the exact command line you used to compile the program.  Optimization settings will affect this.

Comment: @rubenvb: It doesn't sound like a compiler bug to me!

Comment: @Oli: well, technically, the program is wellformed, and then technically, optimizations can't change the result of running the program, no? Of course the code itself is flawed, but the outcome is still changed by optimization. Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: @rubenvb: The program is indeed well-formed, but it's not specified in the standard whether the compiler has to perform tail-call optimization or not!

Comment: @rubenvb All programs contain one potential case of undefined behavior: exceeding resource limits.  An optimized program could use less resources (or vice versa), so it wouldn't have the undefined behavior a non-optimized program would.  (In this case: the optimizer succeeds in converting the recursion into a loop, so you no longer get stack overflow.)

Comment: @Oli: It's not a tail-call.  Still, there is a non-recursive equivalent version.  I think I said that in my answer hours ago, including an example of such equivalent version.  @James: The optimizer not only succeeds in converting recursion into a loop, it sometimes succeeds in precalculating the result, entirely removing both the function call and iteration.

Comment: IMO, the optimizer fails here, and it strengthens my opinion (not just my opinion, NASA and DoD ban the use of optimization in some cases) that optimization can be a very bad idea. I agree with the "It doesn't work" sentiment.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, you're right, it's not true tail-call.  @David: Why do you say that "the optimizer fails here"?

Comment: @David: I definitely agree with @Oli that the optimizer isn't failing.  The original code is begging to cause a stack overflow.  It's no more broken after optimization than it was before.

Comment: @Oli: Because the optimizer should not change the "correct" behavior of segfault on multiply(12, -7) to something else. The program is ill-formed, and optimization should not change that.

Comment: @David: It's not ill-formed (although it's clearly not the design the OP intended).  Seg-fault is not the "correct" behaviour here, it's just one possible outcome given finite resources.  See @James' comment above.

Comment: @Oli: Hand-execute multiply(12, -7) and then tell me the program is well-formed.

Comment: @David: If the program invokes UB, then it's not the compiler's fault; it's not required to find it, but it is allowed to assume that you don't invoke any.  If the program doesn't invoke UB, then it's not ill-formed, it's just got typos.  Again, it's not the compiler's responsibility to find this sort of thing (how could it?).

Comment: @David: Undefined behavior doesn't mean "it crashes predictably".  It means there are no constraints on what the compiler is allowed to do.  The C++ standard doesn't mention segfaults.

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. IMO, this optimization is wrong. If the stack is large enough, `multiply(12,-7) "works" because 2s complement overflow happens to do the right thing. Overflow is undefined behavior. The optimizer should not have optimized the recursion into multiplication. I don't trust optimizers, and this solidifies that mistrust in my mind.

Comment: @David: (Late reply; didn't see your comment) In this particular case, yes, there is undefined behaviour involved.  But that is a red herring,  It would be trivial to invent an equivalent, well-defined example (based on unsigned integers, for instance) that could still result in stack-overflow or not, depending on what optimisations the compiler chose.  There are reasons not to trust optimisers, but this is not one of them!

Answer (score 5):

The output from the code below should give a very strong clue ;)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int multiply(int a, int b)
{
  cout << "a = " << a << "\tb = " << b << std::endl;
  if ( !b )
     return 0;
  else
     return a + multiply(a, b ? --b : ++b );
}

int main() {
        cout << multiply(12, 7) << endl;
        cout << multiply(12, -7) << endl;
        cout << multiply(-12, -7) << endl;
        cout << multiply(-12, 7) << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

It looks to me like it's getting the answer by going the long way.

**Edit:** In response to the comment from Nawaz below, the first method works because of the vagaries of two's complement signed integer arithmetic.  Like I said, it takes the long way around.  It is enabled, as others have pointed out because of some compiler optimization or another.  You can see this in the code below for the test input previously provided:

```
int mul2(int a, int b)
{
    int rv = 0;
    while (b--) rv += a;
    return rv;
}
```

It in fact should work for any pair of integers but will take some time to run in some case (but I expect you weren't interested in efficiency in any event).

The second case does not work because your conditional `b > 0 ? --b : ++b` essentially converts `b` to `abs(b)`.  That is, you only add 7 times in your test case even though b = -7.  If you wanted it to behave the way I think you wanted it to behave you would instead need to do something like:

```
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
  if ( !b )
     return 0;
  else if (b < 0)
     return -a + multiply(-a, -b-1);
  else
     return a + multiply(a, --b);
}
```

**Edit 2:** Try this instead:

```
short multiply(short a, short b)
{
  if ( !b )
     return 0;
  else
     return a + multiply(a, b ? --b : ++b );
}
```

and

```
short multiply(short a, short b)
{
  if ( !b )
     return 0;
  else
     return a + multiply(a, --b);
}
```

Both of these compile, run and return the same (correct) result with or without optimization.  As others have pointed out, the cause of the execution time difference you are seeing can only be attributed to the way the compiler is optimizing your code.  You will need to analyze the assembly code of the two methods to determine the root cause of the time discrepancies.

Comment: Oh god yes ! When somethinggoes wrong, put some logs ! You don't know what's wrong ? Put some more log ! Still don't know ? MORE LOGS ! Maybe a debugger coould be usefull too :D

Comment: @deadalnix: Point taken, and I agree.  This seemed easier and quicker to post than to try to figure out how to post the output from a debugger, though.

Comment: I actually have no problems with both approach. The point is to have some more information. Information is almost always the key to effiscient understanding of a program.

Comment: Do NOT change the code if you wish to understand the effect of optimizations (running in a debugger is fine, as long as you don't have a fancy JIT compiler that detects the debugger and turns off optimization).

Comment: @andand: It doesn't answer the question. Why the first works, and second doesn't, is the question.

Comment: @andand: Still doesn't answer. In the second version, I didn't use `b > 0 ? --b : ++b`. I used simply `--b` which doesn't work.

Comment: @Nawaz: clearly you haven't even tried to understand either my answer or @jyoung's or you wouldn't be stuck on this idea that it isn't working.  Look at your ideone output again.  Do you even know what `SIGXCPU` means?  Hint: there's an explanation right next to it.

Comment: @nawaz: Have you looked at the assembly code produced?  I get the same results others have seen using optimization / no optimization.

Comment: @Ben To be fair to Nawaz, it's not that obvious what's going on.  Still, the answers pointing out that neither version is correct (since both lead to numeric overflow in a signed `int`, which is undefined behavior), *and* the explanations concerning optimization, should point the way: `multiply(a, --b)` results in tail recursion optimization, changing the recursion into a loop; apparently, the compiler isn't able to do this with `multiply(a, b ? --b : ++ b)`, and he is getting a stack overflow.  As a guess, because he never did say what happened when it didn't work, and what the input was.

Comment: @James: Those "worked" and "didn't work" in the question are links.  `multiply(a, --b)` exceeded the time limit ideone sets with `ulimit`, while `multiply(a, b ? --b : ++ b)` returns immediately.  No stack in either, at least with the optimization settings used by ideone.

Comment: The second edit still goes the long way around, at least when compiled unoptimized or with low optimization. It "works" because the stack does grow quite as large with shorts as it does with ints.

Comment: @David Hammen: That was exactly the point I was trying to make. The fact that they both run and return "correct" results in a timely manner demonstrates there's no fundamental difference in the validity (or lack thereof) of the two approaches. It highlights the differences in the way the two are optimized when using ints instead of shorts when loaded onto ideone or when using GCC (which is what I used).

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work (even your short version) if you enable trapping of math errors. That you typically have to enable such trapping is irrelevant. Overflow is undefined behavior per ISO/IEC 14882:2003 5.5.

Comment: @David Hammen:  Again, I don't dispute or in any way disagree with anything you say.  That in mind, however, the whole point of the OP was to explore why one behavior (undefined or not) was observed under one set of circumstances and another, different behavior was observed under what appeared to be a logically identical set of circumstances.  The difference can reasonably be attributed to both the fact that integer arithmetic overflow behavior is undefined as well as differences in the way the compiler optimizes the code.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it has nothing to do with --b, but with your algorithm.

If b < 0, what do you excpect ? You will loop indefinitively and ends up with a stack overflow.

This is why you have the right result at first multiply(12, 7) but then your program fail when you call multiply(12, -7).

Comment: This explains why just `--b` doesn't work. But why does `b ? --b : ++b` work? The condition should be always true, thus always leading to `--b`, since `b` is always nonzero at that point.

Comment: This other case shouldn't work either. You should try to see what the compiler assemble, I'm pretty sure it's different from what you wrote. Can you try it whith number that doesn't have binary special properties (like 7) ?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way 2's complement numbers work, your code is "correct" for both positive and negative values for b.  It is just that for negative b's, any recursive version needs a big stack to work.  So any time the compiler emits a nonrecursive version, you have working code.  So it boils down to: what rule does my complier use internally to determine when to emit nonrecursive code. That just depends on how the compiler was written.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms of `multiply` crash in Visual Studio with a stack overflow, when `b` is negative.

So, the answer is, neither form is correct.  Likely what is happening in `gcc` is that, due to some quirk *(not a bug!)* the compiler is optimizing away the tail-recursion in the first example but not the second.

---

As a side note, even if you change it to `b > 0 ? --b : ++b`, you are still not multiplying by the sign of `b` (eg. `multiply(-1, -1) == -1`)

Answer (score -1):

> But what is surprising to me is, what I did not intend to write does work.

Apparently what's happening is that at optimization level 2 in g++ the compiler correctly sees that if b is positive, your code is equivalent to a*b. It also apparently sees that if b is negative your code invokes undefined behavior. The compiler optimizes that undefined behavior away by generalizing to a*b in all cases. Here is the assembler from g++ -O2 (i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1):

```
.globl __Z8multiplyii
__Z8multiplyii:
LFB1477:
   pushq %rbp
LCFI0:
   movq  %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
   xorl  %eax, %eax
   testl %esi, %esi
   je L5
   movl  %esi, %eax
   imull %edi, %eax
L5:
   leave
   ret
```

I don't trust optimizers. IMO the compiler's response to recognizing the undefined behavior should be failure to compile rather than optimizing the undefined behavior away.

**Edit**

Rather than adding another answer as another answer, I'll add another answer as an edit.

Ask any physicist the value of the infinite sum 1+2+3+... and they'll tell you that it is -1/12. (e.g., see http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-winter2004/zeta.pdf). This going the long way around works by a similar trick of twos complement arithmetic. A solution that does not involve going the long way around for negative numbers:

```
int multiply (int a, int b) {
   if (b == 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   else if (b < 0) {
      return -multiply (a, -b);
   }
   else {
      return a + multiply(a, b-1);
   }
}
```

Even at high levels of optimization, my compiler is no longer smart enough to recognize the above as multiplication. Split the above into two functions and the compiler once again does recognize that what is being done is integer multiplication:

```
int multiplyu(int a, unsigned int b) {
   return (b == 0) ? 0 : a + multiplyu(a, b-1);
}

int multiply(int a, int b) {
   return (b < 0) ? -multiplyu (a, -b) : multiplyu (a, b); 
}
```

Comment: ideone.com doesn't use any optimization, I think. Or if it does, then it does use same for both programs.

Comment: I have tested the code _as written_ on ideone with various optimization levels. I get a segfault when the code is compiled with no optimization or with -O1. When I compile with -O2 I get the results as presented on ideone. I also looked at the assembly. Compile without optimization and multiply() is recursive, with b autodecremented. Compile with -O1 and multiply() is still recursive, but --b is replaced with b-1. Compiling with -O2 replaces the recursion with integer multiplication.

Comment: Very often, you'll find that it's -O0 that will mask UB, and that higher settings will expose it.  This happens to be a case where the reverse is true.  Note also that UB != crash.  The whole point is that the behaviour is undefined; so "optimizing the UB away" doesn't really make sense.